# While editing the HTMl element in shopware 4.2.3 .Its giving js error and i am not able to edit

Tags: javascript, shopware

While editing the HTML element in shopware 4.2.3 .Its giving a JavaScript error and I am not able to edit.

Please check the screenshot [image: Screenshot]

Screenshot's [External URL](http://screencast.com/t/FNxyJnPTl)

**Error**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
>   ext-all.js?201404291539:21

Answer (score 1):

try the simplest way and update to the latest version 4.3.2:
http://wiki.shopware.com/Downloads_cat_448.html